# What could be causing my particle animation to display incorrect coordinates despite correct distance and force calculations?

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I am trying to understand how Math.atan2(dy, dx) and Math.cos() and Math.sin() inside the update() function work.
in this code, mouse coordinates are x: 740 y: 260 and one of the particle's coords are x:673 y: 226, speedX: 0.5 and speedY: 0.5
when I clicked the mouse, the particle traveled in the opposite direction, speedX: -0.5 and speedY: -0.5 and arrived at coordinates x: 536 y: 204 aprox. can you explain why?

my calculations show that the distance between the particle and the mouse: dx = 673 - 740 = -67, dy = 226 - 260 = -34, and distance = sqrt((-67)^2 + (-34)^2) ≈ 76.655.

Since the distance (76.655) is smaller than the mouse radius (100), the particle is affected by the repulsive force.

The angle between the particle and the mouse is calculated using atan2: angle = atan2(-34, -67) ≈ -2.701 radians.

The force is calculated using the formula: force = 100 / 76.655 ≈ 1.303.

The particle's pushX and pushY values are updated based on the calculated force and angle: pushX = cos(-2.701) * 1.303 ≈ -1.094, pushY = sin(-2.701) * 1.303 ≈ -0.465.

The particle's position is updated: x = 673 + (-1.094) + 0.5 ≈ 172.406, y = 226 + (-0.465) + 0.5 ≈ 225.035..

As a result, the particle moves away from the mouse in the opposite direction (since pushX and pushY are negative) and arrives at the new coordinates (x ≈ 172.406, y ≈ 225.035). so I dont understand how the particle instead arrived at coordinates x: 536 y: 204 aprox.

```
       class Point {
            constructor(effect) {
                this.effect = effect;
                this.radius = 15;
                this.x = this.radius + Math.random() * (this.effect.width - this.radius * 2);
                this.y = this.radius + Math.random() * (this.effect.height - this.radius * 2);
                this.speedX = 0.5;
                this.speedY = 0.5;
                this.pushX = 0;
                this.pushY = 0;
                this.friction = 0.95;
            }

            draw(context) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                context.fill();
            }

            update() {
                if(this.effect.mouse.pressed) {
                    const dx = this.x - this.effect.mouse.x;
                    const dy = this.y - this.effect.mouse.y;
                    const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                    const force = this.effect.mouse.radius / distance;
                    if(distance < this.effect.mouse.radius) {
                        const angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
                        this.pushX += Math.cos(angle) * force;
                        this.pushY += Math.sin(angle) * force;
                    }

                }
                this.x += (this.pushX *= this.friction) + this.speedX;
                this.y += (this.pushY *= this.friction) + this.speedY;
                if(this.x < this.radius) {
                    this.x = this.radius;
                    this.speedX *= -1;
                } else if(this.x > this.effect.width - this.radius) {
                    this.x = this.effect.width - this.radius;
                    this.speedX *= -1;
                }
                if(this.y < this.radius) {
                    this.y = this.radius;
                    this.speedY *= -1;
                } else if(this.y > this.effect.height - this.radius) {
                    this.y = this.effect.height - this.radius;
                    this.speedY *= -1;
                }
            }
        }

        class Effect {
            constructor(canvas, context) {
                this.canvas = canvas;
                this.width = canvas.width;
                this.height = canvas.height;
                this.particles = [];
                this.numberOfParticles = 20;
                this.createParticles();

                this.mouse = {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    radius: 100,
                    pressed: false,
                }

                window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
                        this.mouse.x = e.x;
                        this.mouse.y = e.y;                
                })

                window.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
                    this.mouse.pressed = true;
                    this.mouse.x = e.x;
                    this.mouse.y = e.y;
                    console.log(this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y);
                })

                window.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
                    this.mouse.pressed = false;
                })

            }

            createParticles() {
                for(let i = 0; i < this.numberOfParticles; i++) {
                    this.particles.push(new Point(this));
                }
            }

            handleParticles(context) {
                this.particles.forEach(particle => {
                    particle.draw(context);
                    particle.update();
                })
            }
        }
        const effect = new Effect(canvas, ctx);

        function animate() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            effect.handleParticles(ctx);
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        }

        animate();
```

I calculated The distance between the particle and the mouse: dx = 673 - 740 = -67, dy = 226 - 260 = -34, and distance = sqrt((-67)^2 + (-34)^2) ≈ 76.655.

Since the distance (76.655) is smaller than the mouse radius (100), the particle is affected by the repulsive force.

The angle between the particle and the mouse is calculated using atan2: angle = atan2(-34, -67) ≈ -2.701 radians.

The force is calculated using the formula: force = 100 / 76.655 ≈ 1.303.

The particle's pushX and pushY values are updated based on the calculated force and angle: pushX = cos(-2.701) * 1.303 ≈ -1.094, pushY = sin(-2.701) * 1.303 ≈ -0.465.

The particle's position is updated: x = 673 + (-1.094) + 0.5 ≈ 172.406, y = 226 + (-0.465) + 0.5 ≈ 225.035.

The particle's new position is within the canvas boundaries, so no bouncing occurs.

As a result, the particle moves away from the mouse in the opposite direction (since pushX and pushY are negative) and arrives at the new coordinates (x ≈ 172.406, y ≈ 225.035). so I dont understand how the particle instead arrived at coordinates x: 536 y: 204 aprox.

Comment: Hi, it looks like there's an error in your expected x pos, maybe a typo? "x = 673 + (-1.094) + 0.5 ≈ 172.406" should maybe be "x = 673 + (-1.094) + 0.5 ≈ 672.406" instead? In any case with the numbers you're using I'd expect the newly updated position to be close to the previous one. I would also have expected the speed to update at some point but I can't see that happening. Might be worth examining a simple scenario: 1 particle and with the speed set to zero maybe?

Comment: Is it possible to provide a functioning example via CodePen?  (This will ease the effort in diagnosing the issue...)